# Golang ttf font in template

Tags: css, templates, go, truetype

I'm trying to get a TTF font to work in a golang template, but it wont render the font. It shows up as regular Times New Roman. I can change fonts using the standard font-family fonts (ex verdana or 'helvetica'), but I cant import a TTF.

All I can seem to find about TTF fonts is libraries to add text to images, but I want to change web fonts. How can I achieve this?

Structure of project is

- /html_templates/portal.html
- /html_teplates/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf
- main.go

Here is the relevant golang code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)
type Portal struct{
    Title string
}
func main(){
    //Create MUX Routing handlers
    http.HandleFunc("/", portal)

    //Start WebServer
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil); err != nil{ panic(err) }
}
func portal(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    //Create template
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("./html_templates/portal.html")

    //Populate struct
    portal := Portal{
        Title: "title",
    }

    //Execute template with struct data
    tmpl.Execute(w, portal)
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ .Title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'comfortaaRegular';
            src: url('Comfortaa-Regular.ttf');
            src: local('comfortaaRegular'), 
                 local('Comfortaa-Regular.ttf'), 
                 url('Comfortaa-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        }
        body{ font-family: 'comfortaaRegular' }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test/p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow the example provided by Google? That includes a specific reference to `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=[family-name]` that you're missing and a more straightforward `font-family=[family-name]` reference. [Link: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need process static files, add this to main func and set url to `/static/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf` in your template

```
//Create MUX Routing for static
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

Here is complete working code

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

type Portal struct{
    Title string
}

func main(){
    //Create MUX Routing handlers
    http.HandleFunc("/", portal)

    //Create MUX Routing for static
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    //Start WebServer
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil); err != nil{ panic(err) }
}

func portal(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    //Create template
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("./html_templates/portal.html")

    //Populate struct
    portal := Portal{
        Title: "title",
    }

    //Execute template with struct data
    tmpl.Execute(w, portal)
}
```

And template

```
<head>
    <title>{{ .Title }}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'comfortaaRegular';
            src: url('/static/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf');
            src: local('comfortaaRegular'),
                 local('Comfortaa-Regular.ttf'),
                 url('/static/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        }
        body{ font-family: 'comfortaaRegular' }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was not aware of the fact that I have to create a fileserver for static content! Thank you!